# Using regex to extract information inside specific brackets when multiple brackets are present

Tags: java, regex

I have a file that contains this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"
    compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
}

deploy {
    deployDir = file("${Home}/osgi/modules")
}
```

and I want to extract the information inside dependencies bracket.

When I tried to use `dependencies.*[^}]` I would get everything except the close bracket for deploy.

How can I get the regex to stop at the first encounter of close bracket?

Comment: I guess `dependencies[^}]*`, or to include the closing brace `dependencies[^}]*}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-greedy search

```
dependencies.*?[^}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, just want to make sure I understand this right: the ? would make it match up to the first occurrence of }?

Comment: @tom: No, `?` is a part of `*?` lazy quantifier that matches as few characters as possible before a non-`}` that is followed by `}`. The regex is a mess, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple to understand way is to match non-close braces:

```
(?<=dependencies \{)[^}]*
```

This has the advantage of not requiring the *dot all* flag (that makes dot match newlines).

You also don't have to worry, or understand, or use, greedy/reluctant quantifiers.

The use of the look behind means that the *entire* match (not a captured group) is your target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negated character class `[^}]` with a `*` quantifier to get to the closing brace, and just use `}` to match it as a literal symbol (it does not need escaping):

```
dependencies[^}]*}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY3rC8/1)

No need for any look-arounds here that only hamper regex performance.